# How to assign a subnet to app configuration in azure via terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

How to assign a subnet to app configuration in azure. I wanted   it to be accessible only for specific subnet

tried configuring azure app config with terraform. Didnt find any way to assign network to it.

Need it to be accessible only from the sub net as it may contain private data

Comment: Azure App Configuration does not support direct connections. However, you can create a private endpoint for it in a specific subnet using Azure Private Link. This is a secure and robust way to control access to Azure App Configuration, which meets many of the security principles that a direct subnet connection would provide.

Comment: How to create a private endpoint to service in terraform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to assign a subnet to the app configuration in Azure via Terraform via private endpoint within a specific subnet for the Azure App Configuration using Azure Private Link I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

Unlike some other Azure services, Azure App Configuration does not allow you to limit access to a specific subnet using direct integration with Virtual Networks (VNets). This means you cannot use subnet-based access restrictions with Azure App Configuration.

A possible way to limit access is to use Azure Private Link, which creates a private endpoint for your Azure App Configuration within a specific subnet. This way, you can control who can access this private endpoint in the VNet. However, this method does not directly set a subnet-based access policy for the App Configuration but only creates a private endpoint in the VNet.

**My terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

# Resource Group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "demorg-vksb"
  location = "West Europe"
}

# Virtual Network
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "demorg-vk-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

# Subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "demovk-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}

# Azure App Configuration
resource "azurerm_app_configuration" "example" {
  name                = "demovk-appconfig"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  sku = "standard"
}

# Private Endpoint for the Azure App Configuration
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "example" {
  name                = "demovk-privateendpoint"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.example.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "demovk-appconfig-connection"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_app_configuration.example.id
    is_manual_connection           = false
    subresource_names              = ["configurationStores"]
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]